# deque reader is printing data as empty

Tags: python

When I run the below script locally I can see data getting printed from the `trend.csv` file, but when I run the script on a server all the values turn up empty.

I can see that there is content in the `trend.csv` file (it is not empty).

How do I make sure that this is really opening the `.csv` file?

Does any one have any ideas on how to debug this or overcome this problem?

```
with open('//data/loc/scripts/trend.csv','rU') as fin:
  reader = csv.reader(fin)
  data   = deque(reader,8)
print data
```

On the server, I get:

```
deque([], maxlen=8)
```

Locally, I get:

```
deque([['06/27/2013', '5'], ['06/27/2013', '8'], ['06/27/2013', '8'], ['06/27/2013', '8'], ['06/27/2013', '8'], ['06/27/2013', '8']], maxlen=8)
```

Comment: is the path to the file correct?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo - yes,its correct

Comment: To start to narrow down the source of the problem, you could try iterating through the file (for line in fin: print fin) and printing each line. If that doesn't work, then you at least know that the problem is with the file/the server's access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break down the problem:

1. Check the file on both your local machine and the server: is it really non-empty?
2. Try reading the file in using some simpler method.

In the latter case, this is one possible approach:

```
with open('//data/loc/scripts/trend.csv','rU') as fin:
  print(fin.read())
```

3. Check the encoding of the file: is it the same on both machines? Perhaps this is why the CSV reading is failing.